# two Vertical lines on an image seperating 3 paragraphs

Tags: html, css

[This is what i am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdJGj.png)

Vertical line on an image separating 3 paragraphs
There is a tutorial regarding how to make a vertical line but there isn't about how to do it on an image(image is the background inside body in div tag with class="container").

What I tried is

```css
        /* Container holding the image and the text */
    .container {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        
      }
      
      /* Top left text */
      .top-left {
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        left: 16px;
      }
      
      /* Top right text */
      .top-right {
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        right: 16px;
      }
      
      
      /* Centered text */
      .top-centered {
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1.5%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      } 
    
      .centered {
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      } 
    
      .vl {
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
      }
```

```html
    <section>
    <div class="container">
        <img id="building-img" src="architecture-building-town-city1.jpg" alt="A tall Building">
        <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
        <div class="top-left"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, <br> 
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <br> Id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. 
         tincidunt vitae semper quis. </p></div> 
        <div class="v1"></div>
        <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
        <div class="top-centered">Centered</div>
        <div class="centered">centered</div>
      </div> 
</section>
```

but it does not even display the vertical line.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Also the image is not a `background-image`, it's an actual image.

Comment: ok so @Paulie_D i changed it to background-image using css. What about vertical lines? should i use the same method above using <div class="v1"></div> and then aplying css to it?

Comment: @AtiqShaikh you can use ```border-right```

Comment: If your image has a meaning, it should remain in the code . For your layout, there is a few options that css offers, flex and column CSS could be used here .Column CSS can show a ruler that you can style like a border. here is an example to show you an approach with image in the HTML, flex for the first row, and column for the columns & ruler : https://jsfiddle.net/ohcaz51d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I achived the partition with the help grid and using div element itself as partition.  Morever background image can be placed depending upon your needs. In following case I used it in whole body, if you wish you can do that below the container etc.

```css
*{
padding : 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
  background: no-repeat url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/1662159/pexels-photo-1662159.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500") ;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container{
   height:100px;
   width:95%;
   display:grid;
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 3px 1fr 3px 1fr;
   justify-content:center;
   align-items:center;
   margin:30px auto;
}

.container>div{
  text-align:center;
}
.border{
  height:70%;
  background-color:black;
  border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Crispiest <br>crust</div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div>Certified<br> Safe</div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div>Extreme <br>Durability</div>
  </div>
</body>
```